# How to use on message event inside on timer event?

Tags: c, can-bus, capl, canoe

I want to execute below code only once. Can I use `on timer` event to execute only once? If yes how can I use `on message` event inside `on timer` event ?

```
on message *
{
    if (this.id = "X")
    {
        setTimer(MyTimer, 10000);
        i = snprintf(buffer, elcount(buffer),"X is there\n");
        filePutString(buffer, elcount(buffer), readHandle);
    }
    else 
    {
        i = snprintf(buffer, elcount(buffer),"X is not there with ID: %d\n",this.id );
        filePutString(buffer, elcount(buffer), readHandle_01);
    }
```

Comment: `on message` executes code whenever a (matching) message is received. There are other events (as far as I remember `on start` and `on prestart`) which are executed when the simulation is started.

Comment: yes right but how do you use on message inside on start event ? is it possiable to

Comment: This might be pseudo code but otherwise `if (this.id = "X")` ought to give you a big compiler warning.

Comment: @vimal what's library are you use to use setTimer ? I don't see the function in the linux's standard  libraries

Comment: @long.kl library is from CANoe tool

Comment: @long.kl The code is not C or C# code, but capl code. "capl" is the programming language used for the "CANoe" CAN bus tool. `setTimer()` is a keyword in capl.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to execute below code only once.

You cant!

The `on message *` event is called **everytime** when a message is received on the bus.

You can add an additional `if` statement to check if a message is already received. Doing so, you can write code that is executed when the first message is received:

```
variables
{
    int thisIsTheFirstMessage = 1;
}

on message *
{
    if(thisIsTheFirstMessage)
    {
        thisIsTheFirstMessage = 0;

        /* Put your code here */
    }
}
```

> If yes how can I use on message event inside on timer event?

The `on timer` event is called whenever a timer expires, the `on message` event is called whenever a message is received.

What do you think under which circumstances a "combination" of both events would be called?

When a timer expires and a message is received in exactly the same microsecond?

The probability that this happens is close to zero.

For this reason, programming languages that support events (CAPL, JavaScript but also some libraries for C++) do not support combining two events.

The only thing that you can do is to combine two events yourself.

Example:

```
on timer myTimer
{
    timerDidNotExpireYet = 0;
    if(messageHasNotBeenReceivedYet)
    {
        /* Code will be executed when the timer
         * expires before the first message */
    }
}

on message *
{
    messageHasNotBeenReceivedYet = 0;
    if(timerDidNotExpireYet)
    {
        /* Code will be executed when a message
         * is received but the timer has not
         * expired, yet */
    }
}
```

> Your question was tagged with: [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

If you want to insert a ".NET node" instead of CAPL code into CANoe, the principle is the same.

> Your question was tagged with: [c](/questions/tagged/c)

Why did you tag your question with the "C" tag?